# Outputting complex JSON from a MySQL result with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json, sencha-touch

I have just completed a Sencha Touch tutorial which is working fine. I'm currently in the process of converting static JSON data file (which the tutorial utilises) into a dynamically generated data (JSON) file from a MySQL database with PHP. The JSON file (a link to the example file is located below) used in the tutorial has a complex stucture and I'm having issues converting my SQL results into the exact JSON format used in the tutorial. The links to the source code are listed below. The focus in on the JSON file (third link). If I can simply replicate this file then the rest of the project will work for me.

The Sencha Touch tutorial is located at:
http://www.sencha.com/learn/intro-to-the-nested-list-component/

All the code for the project can be located at (I'm only allowed to post two links to I hope you can interpret the link below): 
github dot com / nelstrom / Sencha-Touch-nested-list-demo

An example of the static JSON data file can be viewed at: https://github.com/senchalearn/Nested-list-demo/blob/master/data/albums.json

I have a database and sql which outputs the data in the following structure:

```
Genre  Artist     Album           Track               Duration 
ROCK   MUSE       Absolution      Intro               0:23
ROCK   MUSE       Absolution      Apolcalypse Please  4:13
ROCK   MUSE       The Resistance  Uprising            5:03
ROCK   SEVENDUST  Next            Hero                3:48
FUNK   PRIMUS     Antipop         The Antipop         5:33
FUNK   PRIMUS     Antipop         Ballad of Bodacious 2:29
```

I have the following php which outputs the JSON but with the incorrect format, unfortunately it was as close as i could get - sorry my PHP is abit average :)

```
$result = mysql_query($query,$link) or die('Errant query:  '.$query);
$model = array();

if(mysql_num_rows($result)) {
    while($e = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $model['Genre'] = $e['Genre'];
        $model['Artist'] = $e['Artist'];
        $model['Album'] = $e['Album'];
        $model['items'][] = array(
                        'text' => $e['Track'],
                        'duration' => $e['Duration']
        );
    }
}  

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array('items'=>$model));}
```

Here is an example of the JSON outputted from the PHP code above:

```
{
    "items": {
        "Genre": "ROCK",
        "Artist": "MUSE",
        "Album": "Absolution",
        "items": [
            {
                "text": "Intro",
                "duration": "0:23"
            },
            {
                "text": "Apolcalypse Please",
                "duration": "4:13"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this JSON format is incorrect. The main issue is looping through and apply the square brackets '[' ']' in the correct places. I have included an abbreviated example below:

```
    {
    "items": [
     {
       "model": "Genre",
       "items": [
         {
           "model": "Artist",
           "items": [
             {
               "model": "Album",
               "items": [
                {
                  "model": "Track",
                  "duration": 96,
                  "text": "Introduction",
                  "items": [

                  ],
                  "info": "",
                  "leaf": true
                 },
                 {
                  "model": "Track",
                  "duration": 155,
                  "text": "Please Accept My Love",
                  "items": [

                  ],
                  "info": "",
                  "leaf": true
                }
              ],
              "text": "Live in Cook County Jail",
              "info": "<p>Live in Cook County Jail is a 1971 live album by B.B. King recorded in Cook County Jail, Chicago, Illinois. It was ranked as number 499 in the book version of Rolling Stone's 500 Greatest Albums of All Time.</p>",
              "leaf": true
            }
          ],
          "text": "B.B.King",
          "info": "<p>Riley B. King aka B. B. King (born September 16th, 1925 in Itta Bena, Mississippi) is a well known American blues guitarist and songwriter. He is among the most respected electric guitarists. </p><p>One of Kingâ€™s trademarks is naming his guitar (Gibson ES335) â€œLucilleâ€. In the 1950s in a bar in Twist, Arkansas two men got into a fight, accidentally knocking over a bucket of burning kerosene (used for heating) and setting the establishment on fire. Risking his life, B.B. King ran back into the collapsing building to retrieve his guitar.</p>",
          "leaf": false
        },
      ],
      "text": "Blues",
      "info": "",
      "leaf": false
    }
  ]
}
```

Thank you in advance for having a look at this, sorry if it's long-winded but I just wanted to ensure I have included everything. Please let me know if your require further information.

Kind Regards

Comment: just so you understand, you are taking a relational database and condensing it all of the way down to one object. In practice this is rarely done (unless it is for archival purposes, which I would just take a snapshot of the db myself...). Instead subsets of the data are 'filtered' using various `SELECT` queries to pick out the specific information that is needed. I understand that you are trying to mimic the tutorial, but as it seems you're just getting started with databases and the such in general, I thought I'd let you know before you try doing something like this with every database call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in one shot by using code below. just make sure that your data is returned SORTED by Genre, Artist, Album, Track.

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result)) {
   $curr_genre = $curr_artist = $curr_album = $curr_track = '';
   $model = $track = $album = $artist = $genre = array();
   $first_row = 1;
   while ($e = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        // every time track changes, create new array and insert into album
        $track['model'] = 'Track';
        $track['info'] = "";
        $track['text'] = $e['Track'];
        $track['duration'] = $e['Duration'];
        $track['leaf'] = TRUE;
        $album['items'][] = $track;
        $track = array();

        // every time album changes, create new array and insert into artist
    if ($curr_album != $e['Album']) {
        $album['model'] = 'Album';
        $album['info'] = "";
        $album['text'] = $curr_album;
        $album['leaf'] = FALSE;
        if (!$first_row) 
    {
        // pop the last item as it's taken one from the next album
        $new_item = array_pop(&$album['items']);
        $artist['items'][] = $album;
        $album = array();
        $album['items'][] = $new_item;
        }
        $curr_album = $e['Album'];

        }

        // every time artist changes, create new array and insert into genre
    if ($curr_artist != $e['Artist']) {
        $artist['model'] = 'Artist';
        $artist['info'] = "";
        $artist['text'] = $curr_artist;
        $artist['leaf'] = FALSE;
        if (!$first_row) 
    {
        $genre["items"][] = $artist;
    $artist = array();
    }
    $curr_artist = $e['Artist'];
    }


        // every time genre changes, create new array and insert into model
    if ($curr_genre != $e['Genre']) {
        $genre['model'] = 'Genre';
        $genre['text'] = $curr_genre;
        $genre['left'] = FALSE;
        if (!$first_row) 
    {
        $model["items"][] = $genre;
    $genre = array();
    }

    $curr_genre = $e['Genre'];
        }

        if ($first_row) {
            $first_row = 0;
        }
    }
  }  
    // now just process the last row

        $album['model'] = 'Album';
        $album['info'] = "";
        $album['text'] = $curr_album;
        $album['leaf'] = FALSE;
        $album['items'][] = $track;

        $artist['model'] = 'Artist';
        $artist['info'] = "";
        $artist['text'] = $curr_artist;
        $artist['leaf'] = FALSE;
        $artist['items'][] = $album;

        $genre['model'] = 'Genre';
        $genre['text'] = $curr_genre;
        $genre['left'] = FALSE;
        $genre["items"][] = $artist;

        $model['items'][] = $genre;
```

Comment: Thankyou very much, all responses were very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would do is to try and recreate the JSON formatted-data. A quick test

```
$array = array(
'items' => array(
    array(
    'model' => 'Genre',
    'items' => array(
        array(
        'model' => 'Artist',
        'items' => array(
            'model' => 'Album',
            'items' => array(array())
        )
        )
    )
    )
)
);
$json = json_encode( $array );
var_dump( $json );
```

This gives a JSON output similar to what you need.

You'll then need to get your data from your database into an array of the relevant format. To avoid multiple passes through the array you're building (which could take a while as the array gets bigger) I'd do this as a two step process.

First

```
$tempData = array();
while($e = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $tempData[$e['Genre']][$e['Artist']][$e['Album']][$e['Track']] = $e['Duration']
}
```

You should then be able to loop through $tempArray and build an array in the right format to create the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky. That's a pretty awful data model.

You'll need to add a few fields and maybe do a bit of work, but try this.

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result)) {
    while($e = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $genreExisted = 0;
        $albumExisted = 0;
        foreach ($model['items'] as $genreKey => $genre) {
            if ($e['Genre'] == $genre['text']) {
                $genreExisted = 1;
                foreach ($genre['items'] as $albumKey => $album) {
                    if ($e['Album'] == $album['text']) {
                        $albumExisted = 1;
                        //add a new track
                        $model['items'][$genreKey]['items'][$albumKey]['items']["model"] = $e['Track'];
                        $model['items'][$genreKey]['items'][$albumKey]['items']["duration"] = $e['Duration'];
                    }
                }
                if ($albumExisted != 1) {
                    //add an album inside the genre
                    $model['items'][$genreKey]['items'][]["model"] = "Album";
                    $model['items'][$genreKey]['items'][]["text"] = $e['Album'];
                }
            }    
        }
        if ($genreExisted != 1) {
            //add a new genre
            $model['items'][]["model"] = "Genre";
            $model['items'][]["text"] = "Blues";
        }
    }
}
```